# Disable multiple buttons easy way?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is there any easy way I can do this? Let's say I have 10 different buttons and a textbox.

```
@IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button10: UIButton!
```

If textBox.text is "bt1", i want only enable button1, and disable the rest, and if textbox.text is "bt2", i want to only enable button2, and disable the rest, and so on...

Comment: Use an `IBOutletCollection` to hold all of the buttons.  Iterate through the collections and disable all but the first button.

Comment: What issues did you run into with your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `IBOutletCollection` of `UIButton`.

And accessing them like that:

```
button[0].enabled = false
```

Iterate through the array to disable all button.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

As I understand it you want to enable/disable buttons depending on some text entered into a textField. I'm assuming you have a method which is called from one of the textField delegate methods.
I'm also assuming that there is a 1 to 1 mapping from the text you enter to the buttons i.e that the user has to type exactly "btn1" - they can't do "button1" or "button 1" or any other variation. This is quite an odd requirement - are you sure this is what you really want?

First, as before put the buttons in an 'IBOutlet' collection:

```
 @IBOutlet var allButtons : [UIButton]!
```

Then, use an enumeration to map the textbox text to the index of the buttons in the collection

```
enum ButtonMapping : String {
  case button1 = "btn1"
  case button2 = "btn2"
//and so on

  func buttonIndex() -> Int {
    switch(self) {
        case button1: return 0
        case button2: return 1
        //and so on
    }
  }
}
```

Then just do something like:

```
func disableButtonsForText(text:String) {
  if let mapping = ButtonMapping(rawValue:text) {
    let activeButton = allButtons[mapping.buttonIndex]
      for button in allButtons {
        if button != activeButton {
          button.enabled = false
        }
      }
   } 
}
```

This will change the state of the buttons *only* when the let binding is successful - i.e. when the string supplied to the `ButtonMapping` constructor is a valid button name. In all other cases, the state of the buttons won't change. You might want to consider adding an `else` clause to reset the state of the buttons to normal if the text is not recognised - not sure what you want here.

Comment: Question updated. I small mistake! Can you please take a look? :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you mustn't necessarily create an array of your buttons. As an alternative---given that these are all the buttons in your View Controller---you can make use of `Mirror(reflecting: ...`:

```
/* ViewController.swift */
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button1.enabled = true
        button2.enabled = true
        button3.enabled = true
        setEnableValueForAllButtons(false, exceptForButton: "button2")

        print(button1.enabled)
        print(button2.enabled)
        print(button3.enabled)

        /* button1.enabled = false
           button2.enabled = true
           button3.enabled = false */
    }

    func setEnableValueForAllButtons(toValue: Bool, exceptForButton: String) {
        let buttons = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.filter { $0.value is UIButton && ($0.label ?? "") != exceptForButton}
        for button in buttons {
            (button.value as? UIButton)?.enabled = toValue
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to only show the button whose property name is entered into a text field, you can simply extend the example above to include the text field, and call the `setEnableValueForAllButtons(...)` function from the  `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn` (hence after you press return after entering a string in the text field) as follows:

```
/* ViewController.swift */
import UIKit    
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!        
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button1.enabled = false
        button2.enabled = false
        button3.enabled = false

        textBox.delegate = self
    }

    func setEnableValueForAllButtons(toValue toValue: Bool, exceptForButton: String) {
        let buttons = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.filter { $0.value is UIButton && ($0.label ?? "") != exceptForButton}
        for button in buttons {
            (button.value as? UIButton)?.enabled = toValue
        }
    }

     // UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        setEnableValueForAllButtons(toValue: true, exceptForButton: "")
        setEnableValueForAllButtons(toValue: false, exceptForButton: textField.text ?? "")

        return true
    }
}
```

If it's important for you to use triggers `"bt1"`, `"bt2"` and so on, you could just rename the names of the button outlets to these values.

[image]